# Title в BottomSheet

Tags: java, android

У меня есть BottomSheet в котором находится RecyclerView, в которые добавляются items, как правильно сделать title в этом BottomSheet? (как на картинке "add new record") Первое, что приходит в голову, это добавить в RecyclerView item просто с текстом, но хотелось бы какого-то более элегантного решения.

метод в котором добавляются items в RecyclerView:

```
private void showBottomSheetDialog() {
            if (behavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }

            mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);


            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sheet, null);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(createItems(), new ItemAdapter.ItemListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(Item item) {
                    if (mBottomSheetDialog != null) {
                        mBottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }));

            mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);
            mBottomSheetDialog.show();
            mBottomSheetDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    mBottomSheetDialog = null;
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mAdapterItem.setListener(null);
        }

        public List<Item> createItems() {
            ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.camera, "from new shoots"));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.folder_multiple_image, "from ready images"));
            return items;
        }
```

Верстка экрана:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#118b0a"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/float_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add_white" />


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="#fff" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Элемент RecyclerView в BottomSheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#787878"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто добавить TextView перед RecyclerView не пробовали?

Comment: @YuraIvanov Пробовала, но у меня этот TextView, не отображается на экране, возможно нужно что-то поменять в верстке CoordinatorLayout, либо LineraLayout, в котором находится RecyclerView, но я не знаю, какие именно параметры нужно поменять, что бы этот текст отобразился.

Comment: А разве нельзя просто добавить в разметку  `LinearLayout`, реализующий BottomSheet (*id/bottom_sheet*) `TextView` с заголовком, перед `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @pavloff  я добавляю TextView в LinearLayout перед RecyclerView, но ничего не происходит, текст не появляется на экране.

Answer (score 1):

Как раз сегодня для себя решал точно такую же задачу)). Решил использовать кликабельную floating action button (FAB). При этом запись Add new record представлена символом "+". FAB при нажатии разворачивается вверх с показом двух дополнительных кнопок, в Вашем случае shots и images.

Comment: у меня есть FAB  с плюсом и понажатую на нее должно появляться именно такой BottomSheet, как на фотографии с тремя надписями.

Comment: если разворачивать FAB так как Вы, получается "пересыщение" информации, что в материал дизайне не камильфо, пользователю достаточно отразить действие пиктограммами..вот ссылка на то, как предлагает это делать google https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0B6GnvA6rl3tYWEZGZFBuc1RxMEk/components_fab_flyouts_do.png

Comment: если зайти, к примеру, в GoogleDrive, и нажать на FAB, то там появится, BottomSheet с заголовком и GreedView с пиктограммами.

Comment: Google Drive несмотря на то, что собрал все под одним названием, предлагает в дальнейшем разнотипные действия.. т.е. создание папки, загрузка (упрощенно -"создание") контента, скан.. т.е. действие разделяется на разные по типу действия.. В данном случае действительно применение bottomsheet оправдано. В Вашем случае идет продолжение одного действия, добавления записи, меняется лишь источник.. поэтому я бы применил все же раскрывающийся вверх FAB

Comment: @ZigZag если пиктограммы не достаточно и нужна подпись, то fab - не лучший вариант.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov а нужна ли подпись в данном случае? тем более повторяющееся from.

Comment: @ZigZag это вопрос не ко мне ) На самом деле список может пополняться, я подозреваю.

Comment: @ZigZag  список может пополнятся, и возможно он будет модифицирован в GreedView и будет просто с пиктограммими (GridView),  как в GoogleDrive.